# No permitir introducir cantidad 0 o negativa JS

Tags: javascript

Quiero que al introducir desde el html en un input una cantidad 0 o negativa no me deje guardar los datos en la base de datos (una indexada). Matizar que el input está definitido de tipo "text" y no "number" porque así lo especifica el ejercicio, de ahí que haya puesto el parseInt.

```
if(parseInt(document.getElementById("cantidad").value) >= 1){
    Productos.cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
}else{
    alert("Error: Las cantidades sólo admiten NÚMEROS mayores o iguales a: 1");
}
```

Agrego aqui el código con el que guardo en la BD. Primero compruebo que no haya ningún campo vacío y si es así, guardo

```
if(document.getElementById("codigo").value == "" || document.getElementById("cantidad").value == "" || document.getElementById("descripcion").value == "" || document.getElementById("precio").value == ""){
    alert("Introduce todos los campos");  
}else{
    abrirBD()
    conexionBD.onsuccess = function (e) {
        e.currentTarget.result.transaction("Productos", "readwrite").objectStore("Productos").add(Productos);
    };
}
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema, veo que lo tienes solucionado.

Comment: Aclarar que el código funciona, es decir, si meto un 0 o un número negativo me sale el alert pero se me guarda en la base de datos

Comment: Deberías mostrar el código donde se guarda el registro en base de datos.

Comment: Lo que quiero es que no se me guarde en la base de datos y ya he lo he intendado de varias formas y no hay manera, se me sigue guardando cuando meto un número negativo o 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estás realizando las validaciones por separado, intenta agregando la validación de "cantidad mayor a 0" dentro del `else`, algo así:

```
if(document.getElementById("codigo").value == "" || document.getElementById("cantidad").value == "" || document.getElementById("descripcion").value == "" || document.getElementById("precio").value == ""){
    alert("Introduce todos los campos");  
}else{

if(parseInt(document.getElementById("cantidad").value) >= 1){
    Productos.cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
    abrirBD();
    conexionBD.onsuccess = function (e) {
        e.currentTarget.result.transaction("Productos", "readwrite").objectStore("Productos").add(Productos);
    };
}else{
    alert("Error: Las cantidades sólo admiten NÚMEROS mayores o iguales a: 1");
  }
}
```

Lo que hice fue agregar la validación en la que todos los campos son diferentes de "", posteriormente dentro del `else` se agrega la siguiente condición, en la que si el valor de `cantidad` es mayor que 0 entonces guarda en base de datos, en caso contrario ejecutará el `alert` donde indica que la cantidad es menor o igual que 0.

Pruébalo, en caso de algún inconveniente puedes comentarlo. Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias.. no se como agradecerte que te hayas tomado un rato para resolverlo. Intenté algo muy parecido antes pero no me funcionaba pero no caí en probarlo de esa manera. Muchas gracias de nuevo. Saludos!!!

Comment: Por nada @Furius, que bueno que te haya sido de ayuda. Un saludo.